# JList position resets to default whenever update occurs

Tags: java, swing, jlist

`list` is to accept input from `Action1` this works, however, whenever a new element is added to the list, the list's position moves back to the default `top-middle` position.

This also occurs when the frame is resized, so as a temporary fix I the line `frame.setResizable(false)` but I do not want that to be permanent.

How would I fix both of these issues?

[image]

[image]

```
import static java.lang.String.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class lists 
{

static String newUrl;
static DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
static int listXCoord = 650;
static int listYCoord = 10;

public static void createGUI()
{

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(800,600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);

    JButton addurl = new JButton("Add URL");
    panel.add(addurl);
    addurl.addActionListener(new Action1());
    JButton remurl = new JButton("Remove URL");
    panel.add(remurl);


    //model.addElement("one");
    //model.addElement("two");
    //model.addElement("three");

    JList list = new JList<String>(model);
    list.setCellRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer());
    list.setVisible(true);
    list.setLocation(listXCoord, listYCoord);
    list.setBackground(new Color(186, 203, 250));
    //list.setLocation(650, 10);


    panel.add(list);
    list.setSize(130, 540);
}
static class Action1 implements ActionListener
{        
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) 
    {

        newUrl = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the URL to be Launched");
        model.addElement(newUrl);
    }
}   
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    createGUI();

} 
}
```

Comment: Try using a layout manager other then `FlowLayout`.  `JList` should also be contained within a `JScrollPane`.  Have a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

Comment: You're fighting the layout manager, and losing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you're fighting the layout manager (`Flowlayout`) and losing.  When you add a new element to the `JList`, the container hierarchy is been revalidated which is causing the layout managers to re-layout the contents of their containers

The basic solution would be to use a different layout, but, `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout`, so instead of adding the `JList` to the `JPanel`, you could simply add it to the `EAST` position of the frame instead

[image: Layout]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Lists {

    static String newUrl;
    static DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    static int listXCoord = 650;
    static int listYCoord = 10;

    public static void createGUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);

        JButton addurl = new JButton("Add URL");
        panel.add(addurl);
        addurl.addActionListener(new Action1());
        JButton remurl = new JButton("Remove URL");
        panel.add(remurl);

        //model.addElement("one");
        //model.addElement("two");
        //model.addElement("three");
        JList list = new JList<String>(model);
        list.setCellRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer());
        list.setVisible(true);
        list.setLocation(listXCoord, listYCoord);
        list.setBackground(new Color(186, 203, 250));
        //list.setLocation(650, 10);

        frame.add(new JScrollPane(list), BorderLayout.EAST);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class Action1 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            newUrl = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the URL to be Launched");
            model.addElement(newUrl);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                createGUI();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) and [How to use FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) for more details.

You should also be calling `setVisible` last, after all the components have been added to the frame, this reduces the possibilities that some of your components won't be displayed when you think they should be.

`JList` will also benefit from been contained within a `JScrollPane`.  See [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

Comment: How the hell are you so fast at answering? When I'm at half the code, you always beat me to post a well documented answer and a runnable example! Damn... I admire you :) MadProgrammer-senpai lol

Comment: btw you have a typo `that some of tour components` (tour -> your)

Comment: @Frakcool Fat fingers ;) - Also, I use a lot of templates and have a little program filled with "common quotes", which makes so much easier to generate answers...All I need know as an AI and I won't need to do anything :P

Comment: Oh... I often answer from work, so I need to do all the job from 0, I'll try to make my own templates...